# Having some trouble with case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to take the first day of each january from 2008 to 2018 then display the day then make a case statement that displays a string of text to go along with it.

I've tried looking up on Oracle guide and can't find anything for this specific context

```
Declare
lv_date date;
day_of_week   VARCHAR2(30);
day_of_week_exp   VARCHAR2(30);
begin
lv_date := TO_DATE('1-Jan-2008','dd-mon-yyyy');
for i in 1..11 
loop
day_of_week := TO_CHAR(lv_date,'DAY');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(day_of_week);

CASE
WHEN day_of_week = 'MONDAY' THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('moody' || 
day_of_week);
end case;

lv_date := ADD_MONTHS(lv_date,12);
end loop;

end;
```

Comment: I understand that I can't use 'MONDAY' and that it actually is coded as 01-JAN-2008 but I have no idea how to convert the day_week_week to the string MONDAY if that makes sense.

Comment: Use the `TO_CHAR` function. [docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129)  [format model docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need PL/SQL, but use SQL to get the desired results directly :

```
select 2007 + level as year,
       trunc(to_date(2007 + level,'YYYY'),'YYYY') as first_day_of_year,
       to_char(trunc(to_date(2007 + level,'YYYY'),'YYYY'),'Day') as first_day_week
  from dual
 connect by level <= 2018 - 2008 + 1;
```

If you want to filter by Mondays then use PL/SQL by converting the above SQL to a cursor :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  for c in 
    ( select 2007 + level as year,
             trunc(to_date(2007 + level,'YYYY'),'YYYY') as first_day_of_year,
             to_char(trunc(to_date(2007 + level,'YYYY'),'YYYY'),'Day') as day_of_week_exp
        from dual
     connect by level <= 2018 - 2008 + 1
    )
  loop
   if trim(c.day_of_week_exp) = 'Monday' then
    dbms_output.put_line('moody' ||c.day_of_week_exp);
   end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bce0d410e47083b80b5903201d031be6)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you what I was looking for was the trim part :D, but the rest of the code made a lot more sense the practices I'm doing doesn't want me to do it this way but it helped.

Comment: Hey @BarbarosÖzhan... Congratulations for earning the gold sql badge, and good luck on pursuing the oracle gold badge! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

BDW, all that was required is to add the else part to your case statement.

CASE  WHEN  day_of_week='MONDAY' THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('moody' || day_of_week);
else null;
end case;